# MySQL Chained Triggers

Tags: mysql, triggers

If I have two tables A and B both with insert triggers on them.

If the table A trigger inserts a row into B then performs an update when would the B trigger fire? Immediately on the insert or would it wait for the A trigger to complete?

using pseudo pseudo code would it be

```
A Trigger Starts
  A Trigger Inserts Row into B
  A Trigger Updates B
A Trigger Ends

B Trigger Fires (after insert)
```

or

```
A Trigger Starts
  A Trigger Inserts Row into B
  B Trigger Fires (after insert)
  A Trigger Updates B
A Trigger Ends
```

Comment: Why inserting into then updating B? You should post, what you're actually trying to do. I'm sure it can be solved in another way.

Comment: Its just a question -  if it turned out the trigger A completed first I would have had a nice little domino effect purring through a pile of table updates - if not I would have a potential mess always teetering on the edge of disaster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could've checked it yourself using a log table (general_log won't help you with this) with code like this

Tables schema

```
CREATE TABLE a (id INT);
CREATE TABLE b (id INT);
CREATE TABLE c (id INT);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tg_log;
CREATE TABLE tg_log 
(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
  dt TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  message VARCHAR(512)
);
```

Triggers

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS tg_a;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tg_a
AFTER INSERT ON a
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO tg_log(message) VALUES('tg_a START');
  INSERT INTO b VALUES (NEW.id);
  INSERT INTO tg_log(message) VALUES('tg_a INSERT INTO b');
  UPDATE b SET id = id + 1 WHERE id = NEW.id;
  INSERT INTO tg_log(message) VALUES('tg_a UPDATE b');
  INSERT INTO tg_log(message) VALUES('tg_a END');
END$$
DELIMITER ;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS tg_b;
DELIMITER $$  
CREATE TRIGGER tg_b
AFTER INSERT ON b
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO tg_log(message) VALUES('tg_b START');
  INSERT INTO c VALUES (NEW.id);
  INSERT INTO tg_log(message) VALUES('tg_b INSERT INTO c');
  INSERT INTO tg_log(message) VALUES('tg_b END');
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Then we insert a row into table a

```
INSERT INTO a VALUES(1);
```

And here is what we see in out log

```
+----+---------------------+--------------------+
| id | dt                  | message            |
+----+---------------------+--------------------+
|  1 | 2013-07-27 23:31:42 | tg_a START         |
|  2 | 2013-07-27 23:31:42 | tg_b START         |
|  3 | 2013-07-27 23:31:42 | tg_b INSERT INTO c |
|  4 | 2013-07-27 23:31:42 | tg_b END           |
|  5 | 2013-07-27 23:31:42 | tg_a INSERT INTO b |
|  6 | 2013-07-27 23:31:42 | tg_a UPDATE b      |
|  7 | 2013-07-27 23:31:42 | tg_a END           |
+----+---------------------+--------------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1e1290/1)** demo

Comment: That's good it means chained triggers can be thought of as nested function calls - saved me a mess and I learned something about transaction logs.